# Blur effect on the right side of scrolling container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I want to achieve blur effect on the items at the end of scrollable container. But it stays on one item even if scrolled further. It should stick to the right side only.

Initial pic

[image]

when scrolled to the right
[image]

```css
.main-container .scrollable-nav {
    width: 75%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    position: absolute;
}

.list-item-container {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 20px;
}

li {
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.right-bg::after {
    content: '';
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999999;
    margin-left: auto;
    top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, .7) 40%, #fff 70%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="scrollable-nav right-bg">
        <ul class="list-item-container ">
            <li class="m-item">menuItem1</li>
            <li class="m-item">menuItem2</li>
            <li class="m-item">menuItem3</li>
            <li class="m-item">menuItem4</li>
            <li class="m-item">menuItem5</li>
            <li class="m-item">menuItem6</li>
            <li class="m-item">menuItem7</li>
            <li class="m-item">menuItem8</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/uLd5bga1/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give the pseudo element directly to the `main-container`.

```css
.main-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
}

.main-container .scrollable-nav {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.list-item-container {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.main-container::after {
  content: '';
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 60px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999999;
  margin-left: auto;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, .7) 40%, #fff 70%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="scrollable-nav right-bg">
    <ul class="list-item-container ">
      <li class="m-item">menuItem1</li>
      <li class="m-item">menuItem2</li>
      <li class="m-item">menuItem3</li>
      <li class="m-item">menuItem4</li>
      <li class="m-item">menuItem5</li>
      <li class="m-item">menuItem6</li>
      <li class="m-item">menuItem7</li>
      <li class="m-item">menuItem8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```